# How can I get rid of an "unused variable" warning in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings, unused-variables

I understand exactly why unused variable warnings occur. I don't want to suppress them in general, because they are incredibly useful in most cases. However, consider the following (contrived) code.

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL saved = [moc save:&error];
NSAssert1(saved, @"Dude!!1! %@!!!", error);
```

Xcode reports that `saved` is an unused variable, when of course it isn't. I suspect this is because `NSAssert1` is a macro. The `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` macro is *not* defined, so Objective C assertions are definitely enabled.

While it doesn't hurt anything, I find it untidy and annoying, and I want to suppress it, but I'm not sure how to do so. Assigning the variable to itself gets rid of the compiler warning, but I'd rather do it the "right" way if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I'm unsure if it's still supported in the new LLVM compiler, but GCC has an "unused" attribute you can use to suppress that warning:

```
BOOL saved __attribute__((unused)) = [moc save:&error];
```

Alternatively (in case LLVM doesn't support the above), you could split the variable declaration into a separate line, guaranteeing that the variable would be "used" whether the macro expands or not:

```
BOOL saved = NO;
saved = [moc save:&error];
```

Answer (score 113):

Using Xcode 4.3.2 and found out that this seems to work (less writing)

```
BOOL saved __unused;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a warning that `'saved' was marked as unused but was used`

Answer (score 38):

In Xcode you can set the warnings for "Unused Variables."  Go to "Build Settings" for the target and filter with the word "unused"

Here is a screenshot: [image: Builld Settings Screenshot]

I suggest you only change it for Debug.  That way you don't miss anything in your release version.

Comment: Did you miss the part of the question where Gregory said "I don't want to suppress them in general, because they are incredibly useful in most cases"?

Comment: @ShermPendley Regardless, this is still useful, it answered my question on how to turn it off globally.

Comment: turning off warnings is a great way to miss bugs. I highly recommend against.

Comment: @orionelenzil - well, yes and no. There is a real interface problem with false positives. The warning pops up constantly while you're writing code if you haven't gotten to the part of the code where you use the variable. Over time, this will train you to ignore the warning meaning you may well miss more important errors. It would better to be able to suppress the error in blocks of code being actively edited.

Comment: Hi, its working fine if i set NO. but my doubt is : i have to set Debug & Release NO ya only Unused Variable: NO? which one i have to set. If i set Totally NO, then its not create any prob during release na?

Answer (score 22):

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL saved = [moc save:&error];
NSAssert1(saved, @"Dude!!1! %@!!!", error);
#pragma unused(saved)
```

Try like this.
It is working for me. It will work for you, too.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a warning that `'saved' was marked as unused but was used`

Answer (score 16):

The only simple and portable way to mark variable as used is… to use it.

```
BOOL saved = ...;
(void)saved; // now used
```

You may be happy with already described compiler-specific extensions, though.

Comment: I prefer this over the ugly #pragma described above.

Comment: Hey bro, nice tip

Answer (score 15):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
    NSUInteger abc; /// Your unused variable
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874017/disable-one-unused-variable-warning#answer-21874217)

Comment: This is the cleanest approach since it disables only the warning between those #pragmas

Answer (score 9):

try with: __unused attribute. Works in Xcode 5

Answer (score 6):

You can set "No" **LLVM compliler 2.0 warning** on "Release" [image]

Answer (score 6):

This is the way you do it in C and therefore also Objective-C.

Even though you do not have warnings enabled, it's always a good idea to mark the return value as explicitly ignored. It also goes to show other developers, that you have not just forgotten about the return value – you have indeed explicitly chosen to ignore it.

```
(void)[moc save:&error];
```

---

EDIT: Compilers ignore casts to `void`, so it should not affect performance – it's just a nice clean human annotation.

Comment: In certain contexts you MUST use this hack to get the Objective-C code to compile. Using `(void)` is the clearest way to go, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make it take up two lines.  Separate the declaration and default value

```
BOOL enabled = NO;

// ...

BOOL enabled;

enabled = NO;
```