# Old code gives "Unused parameter" error but never has before now

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, parameters, compiler-errors

I've opened up some old iOS code and when I try to build it I get an "unused parameter" error for code like this:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Search Bar isn't used in this function");
}
```

This is the first time I've ever seen an Objective-C compiler spit out errors (not warnings) for this. Since a lot of iOS calls don't necessarily use the passing arguments (examples being a lot of callbacks), I need help in getting rid of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution # 1)

In your Xcode project's "Build Settings", there's a parameter for "Unused Parameters".

Reset that from `YES` to `NO`.
[image: Unused Parameters Warnings]

Solution # 2 (available with Xcode 4):

In Xcode 4.3.2 or higher use `__unused`.

[(THANKS to Tim Bodeit's comment below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10578498/1984384)

Solution # 3)

Put `#pragma unused (searchBar)` in your code, preferably right underneath the line in your implementation where the function is declared.

I.E.

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    #pragma unused (searchBar)
    NSLog(@"Search Bar isn't used in this function");
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, the XCode setting for the unused parameter warning already reads 'NO'. I'm really hoping not to have to inject code everywhere. Is there some other compiler (or other) setting I can look into?

Comment: does the Setting read "NO" under the Resolved column for your ***target*** (not just the project)?  Also, do you have "treat warnings as errors" set to yes in your project or target settings?

Comment: It's listed as 'NO' in every column for both the project and the target. Treat warnings as errors is set to 'NO' in both as well.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmm... you may want to edit your question to include the Build Log output of some of the errors you're seeing. I'm running out of ideas here.

Comment: So I've gotten rid of the error by removing -Werror and -Wextra. The first tag makes warnings turn into errors. I don't like to have this off right now but I'm stuck. Going to accept your answer.

Comment: I had to remove -Wall on older third party projects with the latest XCode 5.1 update or I'd get "unused warnings" into compiler errors even if I disable that particular warning in the project itself or as an independent flag.

Comment: **CORRECTION** ^^ Above: The actual reason was "treat errors as warnings" compiler flag was enabled and Xcode has new warnings that it did not before so thus new errors showed up. Removing -Wall just made these new warnings disappear and thus not causes errors.

Comment: The solution #2 is great.

Comment: In Xcode 4.3.2 or higher use `__unused` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10578498/1984384