# Xcode: how to force build under "unused function" and "unused parameters" failures

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.3, zxing

Hi I am trying to incorporate the zxing qr code reader into my app. I checked out the svn directly from google code website and also added all the header path in my project settings. However when I try to build the project I am getting a lot of "unused function" and "unused parameters" failures and thus cannot build.

for example, there is a method in the ZXingWidget project called "- (void)cancel:(id)sender" and I am getting errors for unused parameter "sender".

Is it possible for me to force build the project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found ans at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015974/old-code-gives-unused-parameter-error-but-never-has-before-now)

"So I've gotten rid of the error by removing -Werror and -Wextra. The first tag makes warnings turn into errors. I don't like to have this off right now but I'm stuck."