# Unused parameter shows error

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication, appdelegate

I am new to objective C . i have created an ARC enabled application and modified build settings like Treat warning as error - YES and unused parameter - YES in Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 warning category in build setting. so in app Delegate file, UI Application in all the methods showing error. please see this attachment .[image]

is it possible to resolve this issue or i need to modify the build setting again like "Unused parameter - NO"?

please guild me too resolve this issue .

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off treat warnings as errors in your settings. This will fix the compiler errors you are getting.

Otherwise you can silence the errors one by one using the `__attribute__(unused)` specifier.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451123/how-can-i-get-rid-of-an-unused-variable-warning-in-xcode)

Comment: I need that feature too. is there any other way to fix?