# NSLocalizedString - Use of undeclared identifier issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nslocalizedstring

I'm using `NSLocalizedString` in a particular message that works fine if the second parameter is passed as a variable, but fails with `Use of undeclared identifier 'NSLocalizedString'` and `Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation` if the second parameter is written exactly the same as the variable was set. I have working code using the variable, which is fine, I just want to understand the reasons for the failure to know how to avoid it in other situations.

With the following declarations:

```
NSString *branchTitle = [branchDictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
NSString *localString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ node title", branchTitle];
```

This works fine with no errors:

```
[navItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(branchTitle, localString)];
```

... but this, which seems identical to me, fails with the errors noted above:

```
[navItem setTitle:NSLocalizedString(branchTitle, [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ node title", branchTitle])];
```

Searching here and elsewhere I haven't found an explanation. I read through a number of hits on each error message and various `NSLocalizedString` issues, but nothing that tied them together. What I found about the second error message implied maybe an issue with clang and the number of commas in the statement, indicating that even though the extra comma is within the `NSMutableString` message, it was still being seen as an extra parameter by `NSLocalizedString`. Does that make any sense?

Not important for the question, but the statement is intended to set the localized version of a navigation bar title based on the English version pulled from a dictionary, which varies for different views. The `NSMutableString` portion defines the comment for the localization based on the English title.

EDIT: After resolving this issue per the accepted answer, below, I noticed another related issue. The declaration of `localString` was producing an `"Unused variable"` compiler warning, though it was clearly being used. This is also due to it being within a C-macro and for completeness, I'm adding a link to a relevant post here about suppressing that warning: [How can I get rid of an “unused variable” warning in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451123/how-can-i-get-rid-of-an-unused-variable-warning-in-xcode/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this is a result of bad C-macro expansion. Indeed, if you write:

```
NSLocalizedString(branchTitle, ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ node title", branchTitle]));
```

this will compile. For some reason, the preprocessor is not handling well the text within `[]` (possibly because it does not know about Objective-C calls) and treats all the elements within `[]` as separate arguments:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

PS: When I wrote bad C-macro expansion, I meant [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html):

> Macro expansion is a tricky operation, fraught with nasty corner cases and situations that render what you thought was a nifty way to optimize the preprocessor's expansion algorithm wrong in quite subtle ways.

Comment: Nice, just adding a set of parentheses fixes it. NSLocalizedString is the first C-macro I've knowingly used within Objective-C, so that's a good tip to keep in mind when others roll around. Thanks!