# Disable one unused variable warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-warnings, unused-variables

How can I disable one warning in one place only?

I have one variable which I temporarily don't use. Xcode shows me a warning about the "unused variable". I want to disable the warning, but for this variable only, not all warnings of this type.

Is it possible without setting/getting this variable's value?

Comment: Well, you could simply NSLog that variable. Or you could just ignore the warning. Any special reason it bothers you so much ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of an "unused variable" warning in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451123/how-can-i-get-rid-of-an-unused-variable-warning-in-xcode)

Comment: @user1349663 Not really a good suggestion to just `NSLog` it. This is just going to cause a load junk in the console that isn't needed.

Comment: @Popeye True. I just suggested it since s/he said that the variable is "temporarily unused" (i.e s/he will use it later and be done with the warning as well as the log. But I get your point.

Comment: I asked about it because: 1)I imported a library as code which has some unused variables but I don't want to edit it; 2)I replaced global #define ... with a static variable - the code is workable, but this string is highlighted as unused (but it is really used in other files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [GCC / Specifying Attributes of Variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) (understood by Clang as well):

```
int x __attribute__ ((unused));
```

or

```
int y __attribute__((unused)) = initialValue ;
```

Comment: almost, you should mention that if it was written `static int x = ...;` then additional code should be added in the middle: `static int x __attribute__ ((unused)) = ...;"

Comment: @user2159978: That is generally so (not only for static variables). I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty simple:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
    NSUInteger abc; /// Your unused variable
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

**But keeping unused variable is redundant and generally bad idea. Unused code should be removed.** If you use git, there all changes are still in your repo and you can revert your code if you found that this variable is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
__unused int theInt = 0;
// there will be no warning, but you are still able to use `theInt` in the future
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest keystroke answer, change:

```
int x; // this variable temporarily unused
```

to:

```
// int x; // this variable temporarily unused
```

and the warning will go. Also you cannot forget to remove it when you need the variable again, which you can do with any approach which leaves the variable declared.

If you want the removal to be a bit more visible, but wish to keep the property that you can't forget to remove it, try:

```
#if 0
int x; // this variable temporarily unused
#endif
```

HTH

Comment: wrong answer. I know about comments `//` and `#if 0`. I need to disable the warning only, but not to delete/comment the variable

Comment: @user2159978 - I did wonder why you'd want to keep an unused variable around. One reason might be to keep the object *size* the same, but that is unlikely for an Objective-C object so I discounted it. Can you say why you need storage allocated for a variable you're not using? Just curious.

Comment: I answered in a comment to my question

Comment: @user2159978 - I see that now. For (2) you should look at `extern` so you have just one variable rather than 1 per file, some unused. For (1) I fail to see why adding an attribute is not an edit, but all methods work and you should pick which one you like!